# TapJoy crash iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tapjoy

I am working on tapjoy publisher SDK integration for my iPhone app.I was working fine but after updating to latest SDK 9.0.3 its started crashing here on this line .

```
[TapjoyConnect requestTapjoyConnect:TAPJOY_ID secretKey:TAPJOY_SECRET_KEY];
```

**Crash description.**

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key closeButton.'

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you added TapjoyPublisherLibrary not advertising lib.

Here is [8.x to 9.x upgrade instruction](https://knowledge.tapjoy.com/en/integration/8-x-to-9-x-upgrade-guide).

```
#import "TapjoyConnect.h"

[TapjoyConnect requestTapjoyConnect:TAPJOY_APP_ID secretKey:TAPJOY_APP_SECRECT_KEY];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getFullScreenAd:) name:TJC_FULL_SCREEN_AD_RESPONSE_NOTIFICATION object:nil];


- (void)getFullScreenAd:(NSNotification*)notifyObj
{
    // Displays a full screen ad, showing the current featured app.
    [TapjoyConnect showFullScreenAd];

}

-(void)showTapJoyAds
{
    // This method asks the tapjoy server for the featured app object.
    [TapjoyConnect getFullScreenAd];
}
```

Comment: I have added TapJoy Publisher library and following files.TapjoyConnect.h    , TapjoyConnectConstants.h    ,TapjoyPublisherLibrary.a  , TapjoyResources.bundle  ..... I dont know why its crashing here "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key closeButton" . Even the same code works fine before for TapJoy version 8.0 . But as i updated the sdk to 9.0.3 . It started crashing.

Comment: add other linker flag: -ObjC   and -all_load

Comment: Already added, following steps mentioned over here.https://knowledge.tapjoy.com/en/integration/getting-started-guide-for-publishers#ios

Comment: ok try this 8.x to 9.x: https://knowledge.tapjoy.com/en/integration/8-x-to-9-x-upgrade-guide

Answer (score 0):

Try changing iOS target to another version, or read tapjoy specs, what iOS required for it.