# TapJoy and UrabnAirship issue iOS issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linker-errors, tapjoy

I am facing an issue with my iPhone app having Urbainairship and TapJoy.

I am already using the Urbanairship for push notifications. When i integrated TapJoy publisher SDK for offer wall and added -loa[image]d_all and  -ObjC flags it shows me duplication errors for few urban airship files. Screenshot 1 and Screenshot 2 attached

It works perfect for when i integrated on a test project without having urbanairship.

However when linker flags are not set it crashes with this description on following line

[TapjoyConnect requestTapjoyConnect:TAPJOY_ID secretKey:TAPJOY_SECRET_KEY];
Crash description:* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key closeButton.'

Comment: are u sure u used `-load_all` instead of `-all_load` ? BTW, can't see any screenshots

Comment: as per TapJoy documentation i am using -all_load and -ObjC linker flags. Even -load_all doesnt make any difference ,Still same issue.https://knowledge.tapjoy.com/en/integration/getting-started-guide-for-publishers#ios   Can you tell me what this linker flag actually do ?

Comment: Duplicate: here is your same question that live : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877796/tapjoy-crash-iphone-app

Comment: iPhoneProcessor.  That issue is not same as this one. That is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key closeButton.'
```

This eror is means there is some connection problem in the UIElements.
Check xib file and respective connections.
If still same error , remove all UI elements and connect again

Comment: Well this crash appear when i try to initiate TapJoy.[TapjoyConnect requestTapjoyConnect:TAPJOY_ID secretKey:TAPJOY_SECRET_KEY];   This is the part of TapJoyBundle. I didnt make any change in that bundle.

Comment: Plz check all classes associated with `TAPJOY` for XIBs